# Django model (Questions) object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

error: 'Questions' object is not iterable

models.py code:

```
class Questions(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 10, unique = True)
body = models.TextField()
category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name = "questions")
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = "questions/%Y/%m/%d", null = True, blank = True)
status = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("questions:ques_detail", args = [self.slug, self.id])
```

views.py code:

```
def QuestionDetail(request, question, pk):
    question = get_object_or_404(Questions, slug = question, id = pk)

    return render(request, "questions/ques_detail.html", {"questions": question})
```

urls.py code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:question>/<int:pk>', QuestionDetail, name = "questiondetail")
```

Comment: Please provide the entire stacktrace.

Comment: You're passing a variable named `questions` to the html template.  I'm just guessing, but I think the template expects that to be a _list_ of questions, and is trying to iterate over it.  But it fails because it is a single question, not a list.

Comment: {% for question in question %}
i write this loop in template. note: i change the questions to question in views.py

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a misunderstanding somewhere.

Indeed what do you want to achieve ?

If you want to retrieve a single instance your code looks good but it does not make any sense to iterate on an instance.

If you want to retrieve a QuerySet, then you would have to create another view. For exemple :

```py
def questions(request):
    questions = get_list_or_404(Questions)
    return render(request, "questions/ques_detail.html", {"questions": questions})
```

Also you should take care of naming your function and variable in a pythonic way.

Some docs might be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404)

Comment: Exception Value: 
get() returned more than one Questions -- it returned 3!

Comment: Are you using get_list_or_404() ?

Comment: yes. i using get_list_or_404 for questions list view